# Generar un mensaje con éxito luego de completar un formulario

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Se puede hacer para que cuando un usuario complete correctamente el formulario genere un mensaje de envió sin tener que generar una pagina extra de envió. La idea que tenia era que por ahí una ves completado el formulario y enviado desaparezca el form y solo aparezca el mensaje de Muchas gracias!, se puede generar algo así eso?

```js
$(".formValidation").on("submit", function(e){
  
  var errorMessage  = $(".errorMessage");
  var hasError = false;
  
  $(".inputValidation").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    
    if($this.val() == ""){
      hasError = true;
      $this.addClass("inputError");
      errorMessage.html("<p>Por favor, complete los siguientes campos.</p>");
      e.preventDefault();
    }if($this.val() != ""){
      $this.removeClass("inputError"); 
    }else{
      return true; 
    }
  }); //Input
  
  errorMessage.slideDown(700);
}); //Form .submit
```

```css
.info-section .imagen-formulario{
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}


.info-section .inputError{
 background-color: #9e46578c!important;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #824747!important;
  color: #fff;
}
.info-section .inputError::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color: #fff;
}

.info-section .errorMessage{
 /*background-color: #d03e3e; */
    color: #fff;
    clear: right;
    display: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 55px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    margin-top: 21px;
}
.info-section .errorMessage p{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 19px 0px 0px 30px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="info-section seccion_form py-0" style="background-color: #b45d3e!important">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 p-0 m-0">
             <figure class="imagen-formulario">
              <img src="http://qkdev.com.ar/pruebas/welivery_web/images/imagen_form.jpg" class="img-fluid">       
             </figure>
             
            </div>   
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 content-half mt-0 px-lg-5 pt-lg-5">
                <div class="head-box mb-5 pl-md-5 mt-2" style="position: relative;">
     <h2 class="text-white text-underline-rb-white">
      Contáctanos
     </h2>
     <hr class="hr_contacto">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <form class="formValidation px-lg-2">
      <div class="form-group">   
        <input type="name" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="ecommerce" placeholder="Ecommerce">
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group">   
        <input type="name" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">   
        <input type="phone" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="phone" placeholder="Teléfono">
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group mb-5">   
        <input type="email" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
      </div>    
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn_enviar_form">ENVIAR</button>
    </form>
    <div class="errorMessage"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Eso lo puedes implementar con un `alert()` en tú código después de realizar las validaciones correspondientes. Si te gustaría mostrar mensajes más estéticos, existen muchas librerías que te servirían para ello, como _toast_, _alertify_, etc.

Comment: Podrias pasarme si tenes a mano algun tipo de ejemplo de como poder hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que sería una buena práctica que validez los campos para que puedas saber si la información que el usuario te ingresó sea la correcta, es decir que en el input que solicites el email te pase el email y no un teléfono, luego de realizar la validación podrías mostrarle una alerta que diga que es todo correcto y que se registró correctamente, pero otra alternativa es utilizar un Modal, puedes usar los de Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/
Si no te gusta su estilo puedes modificarlo con CSS, continuando con la explicación una vez que hagas la verificación en una variable Booleana que de por defecto este en false haz que se convierta en true y ahí ejecute el modal mostrando un mensaje te mando un saludo! Cualquier cosa aquí estoy

Comment: Hola aqui he especificado mejor el ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/213821/armado-de-formulario-phpmailer de lo que estoy queriendo hacer

Answer (score 0):

Intenta definir una función que evalué si el formulario es correcto de manera que puedas tomar ese elemento, así que tendrás que definir un elemento `div` antes del formulario con el atributo `id="ejemplo"` de forma que `<form class="formValidation px-lg-2">` este incluido, entonces si la entrada del usuario ha sido correcta tu función debe usar `getElementById` tomando el `id` que has definido anterior y luego modificas el atributo `innerHTML = 'Muchas Gracias'`. Creo que podrías hacer lo que propones manipulando los elementos **html**, mas informacion la puedes encontrar aqui: [PHP DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.dom.php).

Answer (score -1):

Sin duda alguna lo que yo haría en este caso es al comprobar que todos los campos están correctamente rellenados, o lo que ud. considere correctamente rellenado, poner una variable 'centinela', esta variable suele ser de tipo Booleano, por lo tanto la inicias a 'false', por ejemplo, y si se cumple el hecho de que el formulario esté correctamente rellenado la pasas a 'true' y después del foreach que tiene pondría otro 'if' en el que compruebo el estado de esa variable, si es false, es que ocurrió algún error y por lo tanto no debería entrar y si es true que entrara y una vez dentro podría ocultar el formulario y mostrar un texto que ud. quisiera, no sé si me explico, si no es así, déjemelo saber.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola aqui he especificado mejor el ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/213821/armado-de-formulario-phpmailer de lo que estoy queriendo hacer