# Armado de formulario phpmailer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, phpmyadmin

Estoy queriendo armar un formulario para un sitio usando PHPMAILER. 
Estoy queriendo hacer pruebas con mi propio Email pero no estoy logrando que me lleguen los mensajes ni tampoco me están funcionado los campos de verificación.

[Este es el sitio de prueba](http://www.morpheuslights.com/prueba/welivery_web/?). Por otro lado tampoco me esta funcionando la validación de los input, quizas he asociado mal el archivo de JS con PHP y si en el FORM solo deberia poner los value con sus nombres.

**La idea es que una vez enviado el formulario aparezca un mensaje de gracias nos pondremos en contacto!**

El armado que estuve haciendo es el siguiente:

```js
$("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(e){
  
  var errorMessage  = $(".errorMessage");
  var validMessage  = $(".validMessage");

  var hasError = false;
  var hasvalid = true;
  
  $(".inputValidation").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    
    if($this.val() == ""){
      hasError = true;
      $this.addClass("inputError");
      errorMessage.html("<p>Por favor, complete los siguientes campos.</p>");
      e.preventDefault();
    }if($this.val() != ""){
      $this.removeClass("inputError"); 

    }else{
      return true; alert(1);
      }
    
    }); //Input

  validMessage.slideDown(700);

  $(".inputValidation").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    
    if($this.val() == ""){
      hasvalid = false;
      $this.addClass("inputError");
      validMessage.html("<p>Por favor, complete los siguientes campos.</p>");
      e.preventDefault();
    }if($this.val() != ""){
      $this.removeClass("inputError"); 

    }else{
      return true; alert(1);
      }
    
    }); //Input
  
  validMessage.slideDown(700);

    /*ajax*/
  if(hasError == false){
      Ecommerce = document.getElementById("exampleInputEcommerce").value;
      Nombre = document.getElementById("exampleInputNombre").value;
      Telefono = document.getElementById("exampleInputPhone").value;
      Email = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1").value; 
      data2= { 
          ecommerce:Ecommerce,
          nombre:Nombre,
          telefono:Telefono,
          email:Email,
          tarea: "envio"
        };
      
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"envio.php",
        data: data2,
        success:function(data){
          console.log("entro");
          /*$('#respuesta').fadeOut('fast').html(
            "Gracias, se a enviado su mensaje"
          );*/
          
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
          $('.validMessage').fadeOut('fast').html(
            "Gracias, se a enviado su mensaje"
          );
          $(".inputValidation").val("");
        } 
        
      });

  }




}); //Form .submit
```

```css
.inputError{
 background-color: #9e46578c!important;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #824747!important;
  color: #fff;
}
 .inputError::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color: #fff;
}

.errorMessage{
 /*background-color: #d03e3e; */
    color: #fff;
    clear: right;
    display: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 55px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    margin-top: 21px;
}
.errorMessage p{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 19px 0px 0px 30px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<form class="formValidation px-lg-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="name" value="ecommerce" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputEcommerce" aria-describedby="ecommerce" placeholder="Ecommerce">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="name" value="nombre" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputNombre" aria-describedby="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="phone" value="telefono" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputPhone" aria-describedby="phone" placeholder="Teléfono">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-5">
    <input type="email" value="email" class="form-control inputValidation" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn_enviar_form mt-sm-5">ENVIAR</button>

</form>
<div class="errorMessage"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
    <?php
function envioMail(){

$ecommerce = $_POST["ecommerce"];
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "marianoandres_17@hotmail.com"; // A RELLENAR. Aquí pondremos el SMTP a utilizar. Por ej. mail.midominio.com
$mail->Username = "marianoandres_17@hotmail.com"; // A RELLENAR. Email de la cuenta de correo. ej.info@midominio.com La cuenta de correo debe ser creada previamente. 
$mail->Password = ""; // A RELLENAR. Aqui pondremos la contraseña de la cuenta de correo
$mail->From = "marianoandres_17@hotmail.com";  // A RELLENAR Desde donde enviamos (Para mostrar). Puede ser el mismo que el email creado previamente.
$mail->FromName = "Mariano"; //A RELLENAR Nombre a mostrar del remitente. 
$mail->Subject = "Mensaje de Welivery"; // Este es el titulo del email.
$mail->AddAddress("marianoandres_17@hotmail.com");/*email de CM*/

$body  = 
"
Se ha informado la descarga del siguiente resultado: $codigoAlerta

Muchas gracias

Equipo PfAst
Pfizer
"; 
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Send();

}
if($_POST){
switch($_POST["tarea"]){
case "envio":envioMail();break;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que visites el sitio de [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), ya que antes de crear el objeto tienes que hacer dos `require`:  primero el `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;` y 
`use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;` despues  `require_once(__DIR__.'/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php');` y 
`require_once(__DIR__.'/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php');` y por ultimo el objeto `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);`

Comment: Phpmailer usa namespace debes instaciarlo con su namespace o comentarlo y instanciarlo normal

Comment: Como sería eso de crear el objeto?? Porque yo de php no entiendo mucho, estuve leyendo algo pero no me ha quedado muy en claro, lo que hice yo fue bajar dos archivos más el archivo php que armé yo. Lo que nose si en el php estoy poniendo bien los datos. Las pruebas que estoy realizando son con mi email para saber si llegan los mensajes. X otro lado en el JavaScript estoy queriendo hacer tbn una validación de Campos cuando están incompletos que no estarían funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

Como sería eso de crear el objeto?? Porque yo de php no entiendo mucho, estuve leyendo algo pero no me ha quedado muy en claro, lo que hice yo fue bajar dos archivos más el archivo php que armé yo. Lo que nose si en el php estoy poniendo bien los datos. Las pruebas que estoy realizando son con mi email para saber si llegan los mensajes. X otro lado en el JavaScript estoy queriendo hacer tbn una validación de Campos cuando están incompletos que no estarían funcionando.